# What's the difference between CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor UIColor setStroke?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

Is there any difference between those two ways of setting stroke color?

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor)

[[UIColor redColor] setStroke]
```

**Example**

```
CGContextRef cr = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cr, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

UIBezierPath *bp = [UIBezierPath new];

[bp stroke];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is longer and pure C. The other is shorter and uses Objective-C. They have the same effect.

Comment: I guess one other difference is that UIColor treats solid colors and patterns the same, but the CG Api uses different functions (and types) for patterns.

Comment: But you can turn a `CGPattern` into a `CGColor` with `CGColorCreateWithPattern`.